# Using Transform to scale multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Ok so what I want to do is take two rows of a table and make them bulge out together.  The best way I have found to do this is with transform using the scale function.  The problem is that one row will cover the other slightly on the verticle axis. I would like the top row to somehow be bumped up by the lower rows expansion or scale them together somehow.  Normally you would just wrap them in a div but with a tr that doesn't work so well.

```
    <tr id="1">
        <td>
           Hello
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
       <td>
          Hello 2
       </td>
   </tr>    
    <style type="text/css">
        .grow{
            -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
            -webkit-transition: 900ms ease;
            backface-visibility: visible;
            transition: 900ms ease;
            transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
        } 
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function flashAccommodation(){
            var row = document.getElementById("1");
            var row2 = document.getElementById("2");
            row.className = row2.className = "grow";
        }
    </script>
```

Thanks to vals for his answer my code below works based on his solution

```
.preGrow1{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: 900ms ease;
    backface-visibility: visible;
    transition: 900ms ease;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.preGrow2{
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: 900ms ease;
    backface-visibility: visible;
    transition: 900ms ease;
    transform-origin: center top;
}

  function flashAccommodation(id){
    var row = document.getElementById("1");
    var row2 = document.getElementById("2");
    row.className = "preGrow1";
    row2.className = "preGrow2";
    row.style.transform = row2.style.transform = "scale(1.2)";
}
```

Comment: .you have two ids: "1" and "2" and you are calling row2.classname and row.classname......how did this sample worked for you?..are you looking to scale the element smoothly when the mouse hovers it?....please clarify

Comment: The Id's are much more complicated in my code so i changed them to 1 and 2 to make it simple.  Its an external action such as a button click that calls flashAccommodation but thats not really relevant to the question.  If i change scale(1.2, 1.2) to scaleX(1.2) both rows will simultaneously grow by 20% horizontally, expanding outside the table to provide a visual bulge, but the text gets a bit funky as its being stretched.  I would like to use scale to avoid this but when i do the bottom row ends up covering up the bottom part of the top row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best option that you have is to set the transform origin so that the zoom itself moves the elements up and down

The transform origin, in the case of a scale, is the point that doesn't move in the transform process.

So, setting it to bottom for the first row makes it move upwards (keeping the bottom line at the same position). And the opposite for the second row.

```css
td {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

tr {
  transition: transform 1s;  
}
table:hover tr {
  transform: scale(1.2);  

}

tr:first-child {
  transform-origin: center bottom;  

}

tr:last-child {
  transform-origin: center top;  

}
```

```html
<table>   
<tr id="1">
        <td>
           Hello
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
       <td>
          Hello 2
       </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: The origin mostly fixes the problem thank you.  I edited my question to show how your answer fixes it